# Showing modal via method call in react app

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

In our react app (we use reactstrap), we've multiple pages from where a confirmation modal can be shown. We do not want to include the [modal code](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/) in every page. Is there a way to do this programmatically by invoking a method?

We can use plain bootstrap modals directly in the public index.html and from the util method use dom selector and invoke the modal but want to avoid this. Any pointers on how to go about this?

Comment: Can you not jut make a modal component that uses the modal code, but allows for dynamic content of the actual modal? Then you can reuse that modal component when needed and simply add the desired modal content as children

Comment: We have the modal component with dynamic content but do not want to include it on every page where this is to be shown.

Comment: Importing a component is only one line, and you can't really use something without importing it, unless it's available globally somewhere (which isn't usually the case for React components). Are these "multiple pages" react components? Or HTML files? Not too sure why importing it is creating an issue

Comment: It's about avoiding repetition. And trying to invoke the modal imperatively. See my answer below on how we achieved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what we did.

Alert Component:

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from "reactstrap";

const Alert = props => {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(props.open ? props.open : true);

  const toggle = () => {
    setModal(!modal);
    if (props.cb) {
      props.cb();
    }
    if (props.reloadPage) {
      window.location.reload();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle}>
        <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>{props.title}</ModalHeader>
        <ModalBody>{props.text}</ModalBody>
        <ModalFooter>
          <Button color="primary" onClick={toggle}>
            Ok
          </Button>
        </ModalFooter>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Alert;
```

Util.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Alert from "./Alert";

const Util = {
  alert: (message, okCb, reload) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Alert
        title="Done"
        text={message}
        cb={() => {
          ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(
            document.getElementById("modalHolder")
          );
          if (okCb) {
            okCb();
          }
        }}
        reloadPage={reload}
      />,
      document.getElementById("modalHolder")
    );
  }
};

export default Util;
```

In index.html we created a dom element:

```
<div id="modalHolder"></div>
```

So to invoke the modal imperatively, call:

```
Util.alert("Data has been saved")
```

Comment: oh I see what you mean now, sorry was confused before. Yeah to do this without the manual `ReactDOM` rendering you'd have to use the React Context API, Redux, or a whole lot of prop drilling. Prop drilling is messy, Redux is an extra dependency, and the Context API can be verbose and a bit of a learning curve, though it's technically the correct "React" way to do it. Though in reality if you've done in that way and it works for you, going back to do it with context may not be worth it priority wise.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is only one modal which can be used across multiple pages(instead of putting one modal in every page), you can put it in the root component usually names as App.

```
import Modal from "somewhere";

function App() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState(false);
  return <>
    <Model isOpen={modal} />
    {/* If you need to toggle modal when clicking something in PageA, you can pass the prop down like this */}
    <PageA onToggleModel={()=>{setModal(!modal)}} /> 
    <PageB />
  </>;
}
```

---

Just in case, doing `import Modal from "somewhere"` in every page wouldn't result in duplicate code in your final bundle. It's totally fine to do that.

Comment: We tried this approach but we've to pass the props down to the components. See the approach we took in the answer below.